# Is there open-source java/c/c++ framework for pipes-and-filters paradigm?

Tags: java, c++, frameworks, filter, pipe

I'm interested in open-source Java/C/C++ framework for pipes-and-filters (like described in that [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321200683)) paradigm.
Can you recommend some?

**EDIT:** I'm looking for as much "pure" (or lightweight) frameworks as possible: frameworks which encourage programming in "pipes-and-filters" technique, without reliance on any standards, such as XML or JMS, but on language only.

Comment: Hmm...the Unix API? We now return you to your regularly scheduled serious answers.

Comment: Does the Unix API hava a java implemnetation? Probably a bit of a pain - to fit with the usual java practices, all processes will have to be wrapped in a chain of BufferReader/InputSreamReader/ByteInputStream filters to have half-way decent performance.

Comment: @mdma: These kinds of concerns (and I have no idea of the answers) are why that's not a useful suggestion...I was just being snarky.

Comment: @dmckee - so was I! :-) But I guess you have to know java to get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just discovered Spring integration framework. Looks like the sample of what I was asking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at chapter 6 of the book you link to, you'll notice it has samples for JMS. A quick visit at Google leads us to a list of open source implementations of JMS: http://java-source.net/open-source/jms

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion! Are there any non-JMS (more lightweight) frameworks you know of?

Comment: Well, what are you looking for? Do you just want to see how it's implemented, or are you looking for something to use in production code?

Comment: Well, preferably, both of these :) For example, why I'm not going for JMS:  I need not library which will handle persistence for me.

Comment: Too bad you're not using C#, LINQ would fit you like a glove ;) Maybe the new fork/join framework could be interesting to you: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp11137.html The code is available at http://javac.info

Answer (score 1):

I know you asked about Java/C/C++, but thought I'd add:

In .NET, the WCF Channel model works like this.

Answer (score 1):

W3C XML Pipline spec, [XProc](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/REC-xproc-20100511/) is kind of pipes and filters.

There's a java implementation [here](http://norman.walsh.name/2007/projects/xproc). XProc comprises a number of processors (XSLT transforms, XPath selects, serializing/deserializing to file) i.e. filters - and these are connected by ports carrying XML data - basically pipes.

Comment: This is interesting, but, unfortunately, tightly bounded to XML world. I'd like to know about as much "pure" as possible frameworks. Still, I think now I know more about existing approaches, thank you!

Comment: Yes, it's XML - your OP didn't say what data you are piping and filtering - it sounded like you were looking for examples of that pattern.  It looks like you you have specific needs in mind - can you update your question to better reflect precisely what you are looking for?